# MFC: Use a dialog's class for a second dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have an dialog with several buttons and sliders on it and am adding another button that should close the dialog and open another that is essentially a mini version it.

I need access to the buttons in the first dialog in the second mini dialog (since they should have the same functionality).

Is there a way to use the class from the first dialog on the second so that I have access to those buttons? I've tried right clicking the dialog and adding a class, but it makes me make a new one instead of being able to use an existing one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generically speaking, when you create the new dialog pass it a reference the dialog that's creating it then access its members as necessary in OnInitDialog

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What do you mean by pass it a reference when creating the dialog? I'm opening it using DoModal, are you talking about in the .h file? Sorry, pretty new to MFC.

Comment: Your dialog is a class in itself. So just make a instance of that class and call it. If you add some flags etc. to the dialogue you can then decide which controls should be hidden.

Comment: If you are adding functionalities to new Dialog then create a subclass of the dialog and override the functions you want and perform your logic and then call base class's function if needed.